# Trouble Deserializing JSON Dictionaries in a huge complex data file

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, json.net

Working on a C# app that consumes a lot of api data and mostly I have not had an issues regarding data deserialization until now.

I have a 200k+ line json file which is 90% deserialized i am just missing one object which i want to contain a dictionary<string, object> which will contain a nested dictionary<string, object>

Json is looking like this

```
{
 "missionRewards": { //[This needs to be the first dictionary<string, Planet> (see code below)]
    "planet_name" : { //[This needs to be the second dictionary<string, Mission> (see code below)]
      "mission_name": {
        everything within the mission object is interpreted correctly, it contains 2 strings and 3 arrays of reward.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Planet name and mission name are dictionary keys because in the actual json file they all have unique names.
"Earth, Mars, Venus etc"

Actual json file can be found here.

```
http://drops.warframestat.us/data/all.json
```

Here is the important bits of my deserialization class

```
public class A
    {
        [JsonProperty("_id")]
        public string Id;

        [JsonProperty("itemName")]
        public string ItemName;

        [JsonProperty("rarity")]
        public string Rarity;

        [JsonProperty("chance")]
        public double Chance;

        [JsonProperty("stage")]
        public string Stage;
    }

    public class B
    {
        [JsonProperty("_id")]
        public string Id;

        [JsonProperty("itemName")]
        public string ItemName;

        [JsonProperty("rarity")]
        public string Rarity;

        [JsonProperty("chance")]
        public double Chance;

        [JsonProperty("stage")]
        public string Stage;
    }

    public class C
    {
        [JsonProperty("_id")]
        public string Id;

        [JsonProperty("itemName")]
        public string ItemName;

        [JsonProperty("rarity")]
        public string Rarity;

        [JsonProperty("chance")]
        public double Chance;

        [JsonProperty("stage")]
        public string Stage;
    }

    public class Rewards
    {
        [JsonProperty("A")]
        public List<A> A;

        [JsonProperty("B")]
        public List<B> B;

        [JsonProperty("C")]
        public List<C> C;

        [JsonProperty("_id")]
        public string Id;

        [JsonProperty("itemName")]
        public string ItemName;

        [JsonProperty("rarity")]
        public string Rarity;

        [JsonProperty("chance")]
        public double Chance;

        [JsonProperty("rotation")]
        public string Rotation;
    }

    public class Mission
    {
        [JsonProperty("gameMode")]
        public string GameMode;

        [JsonProperty("isEvent")]
        public bool IsEvent;

        [JsonProperty("rewards")]
        public Rewards Rewards;
    }

    public class Planet
    {
        public Dictionary<string, Mission> Missions;
    }

    public class MissionRewards
    {
        public Dictionary<string, Planet> Planets;
    }
```

What i have tried so far is declaring a [JsonDictionary] param on the dictionaries and as well tried using a list of objects, a dictionary of untyped objects but i cannot seem to get anything to work because the json deserializer does not recognize either of the objects as a dictionary.

I am using Newtonsoft.JSON for operations.

Any pointers on how i can fix the situation i find myself in. Basically my main concern is tying the identifying name to the object once its been deserialized and i cannot do that using lists.

Comment: This is how a json class converte creates it but as you can see each mission is declared individually as its own object which is why i would rather have a dictionary.

https://pastebin.com/0KXLq3Bs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create this type

```
public class WarframeStats{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Mission>> MissionRewards;
}
```

and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WarframeStats>(jsonString);`

You will get your parsed JSON as nested dictionary. In your original post it wasn't deserializing as you expected because there is no property named "Missions" nor "Planets".JSONConvert doesn't know what to assign to those variables. There might be some ways of making it assign to them but might have to hit up the official docs for that.

Comment: I understand the reasoning that it wasn't deserializing it because of the un-named types, i was hoping someone here has worked with an issue like this before because i wasnt able to find info on the docs. It would be good to use something like JsonProperty with an array of strings that it could be, that wouldnt be too bad to implement.

Comment: One way to do it is by parsing manually using JObject. You iterate over each node and create the respective DTOs as you go.

Comment: Anyways after solving it i ran into a second problem that I understand what i need to do to make it work i just cant figure out the JsonConverter library, the problem is that missions can either have the object Rewards or an array of Reward which is the same as rewards just without the a,b,c lists I can make a separate question if you want me to. I am trying to write the json convert abstract class for just the rewards part of the file but have a sneaking suspicion i will need to build out the entire file in the custom converter.

Comment: I fixed the second issue by changing mission to object and then typecasting it a for loop when im reading the data. Its slow currently but works, will improve the efficiency next.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way:

Instead of Planet containing a dictionary, have Planet subclass a Dictionary.

```
public class Root {
    public Dictionary<string, Planet> MissionRewards { get; set; }
}

public class Planet : Dictionary<string, Mission> {

}

public class Mission: Dictionary<string, object> {

}
```